# How to deploy all resources to another region using stack-sets in same aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

It seems that this question has already been asked in a different manner on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634750/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deploy-a-multi-region-cloudformation-stack-that-includ). But still, my confusion is not clear. I am struggling to copy all my resources from one region to another using stacksets.

I was successful in creating admin and target account trust relationship within the same owner account with the help from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525634/can-i-use-cloudformation-stacksets-to-deploy-to-multiple-regions-in-my-own-accou).

I created a template of resources in the current region using cloudformer and saved it to the S3 bucket. But I am facing error when I am trying to deploy the resources using this template to another region with stacksets.

Error's like xxx availability zone doesn't exist or failed to create xxx resources or InvalidZone.NotFound etc.

Please someone brief about the correct way to deploy regional resources to another region. Should I use sample templates of stacksets or predefined template?

Answer (score 0):

The key point to understand is that the template used to create the stack will be the same in each region.  It sounds like you have a template that may reference something like an availability zone, so that template would work in the region where that availability zone exists, but fail in a region where that availability zone does not exist.

It sounds like you would benefit by using Conditions in your template, along with a map, so you can reference values that are region-specific, for example.  Check out this documentation which includes examples that seem relevant based on your description:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

If the template works in any region, it will work via Stack Sets.  Try creating a very simple template that only creates one simple thing and run that.  You can get a feel for how it will work as it gets more complex.